# Including Chart.js in a webpage without node.js and without CDN

Tags: javascript, node.js, chart.js

I'm trying to use chart.js in a project I'm working on but on the system I'm on I won't have access to node.js or a CDN to link to it externally. I have to have it somewhere where my project can access it without increasing the complexity or overhead for configuring the web server to interact with my project.

Is there a way to do this? If it helps, I'm using django framework as a backend

Answer (score 4):

You can clone their [GitHub](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/releases/tag/v3.1.0) repo and build it yourself (`npm run build` from what I see from their `package.json`). You will need npm for this one step, but you will have a `dist` folder in the repository where you find all the files you need. Serve them as static resources from Django and include them in your templates as needed.

Just bear in mind that, as the say (quote below), you will be in charge of keeping Chart.js current yourself.

> If you download or clone the repository, you must build Chart.js to generate the dist files. Chart.js no longer comes with prebuilt release versions, so an alternative option to downloading the repo is strongly advised.

Comment: So the dist folder is the only one I need to bundle with my project?

Comment: If you follow the normal node build cycle. That means, you have to 'npm install' all dependencies of Chart.js, then, run 'npm run build' and you will get a dist folder with the build files in it. You are responsible for putting them in a place in your project where they are reachable.